# Iterating Microsoft Graph objects using PageIterator in an API called from Browser

Tags: azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have code similar to the following to read objects from `Microsoft Graph`. The following code in an `Azure Function` which is called by a `React JavaScript SPA` application. My requirement is to retrieve 10 groups at a time from with a paging support in  the `React` application. I can't retrieve all the groups to the browser from the server which comes to more than 500 or more.

How can I use `PageIterator` to iterate 10 groups at a time with calls from the `React` app? Let us assume the `React app` made the first call to the `Azure Function` to get 10 groups. When the second call come from the `React` app, the instance of the `PageIterator` is already destroyed. I have to make such 50 calls from the `React` app on the browser to get all the 500 groups.

```
// create a list to hold the groups
var groups = new List<Group>();
// create a page iterator to iterate through the pages of the response
var pageIterator = PageIterator<Group, Microsoft.Graph.Beta.Groups.Delta.DeltaResponse>.CreatePageIterator(graphClient, deltaResponse, group => 
{
    groups.Add(group);
    return true;
});

// This will iterate follow through the odata.nextLink until the last page is reached with an odata.deltaLink
await pageIterator.IterateAsync();

if (pageIterator.State == PagingState.Delta) 
{
    await Task.Delay(30000);// wait for some time for changes to occur.
    // call delta again with the deltaLink to get the next page of results
    Console.WriteLine("Calling delta again with deltaLink");
    Console.WriteLine("DeltaLink url is: " + pageIterator.Deltalink);
    await pageIterator.IterateAsync();
}
```